# Query a range of date

Tags: sql

Im trying to query a sort of from - to date.
e.g. 20-01-2010 to 20-02-2010. this should include the mentioned dates.

i've tried the following queries but none works.

```
select * 
  from [tableName] 
 where date >= '20-01-2010' 
   AND date <= '20-02-2010'
```

but the date where date is equal to 20-02-2010 does not show. i don't know why.

---

```
select * 
  from [tableName] 
 where date between '20-01-2010' 
            AND '20-02-2010'
```

the mentioned dates is not included in the results. i want it to be included in the results.

please help.

thanks in advance! :)

Comment: what is the data type of the 'date' field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the replies. 
I figured out the problem.

The reason why the query below doesn't work is because the value of the date field has hh:mm:ss since it's datetime. If you compare to ordinary date, the time part will be 0. That's why data w/ date '20-02-2010' doesn't show up in my result set since the data has hh:mm:ss not equal to '00:00:00.000'.

```
SELECT * FROM[tableName] WHERE date >= '20-01-2010' AND date <= '20-02-2010'
```

The query below works now. Just added a time parameter

```
SELECT* FROM [tableName] WHERE date >= '20-01-2010' AND date <= '20-02-2010 23:59:59.000'
```

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you don't have **datetime values in your table where the time value is not 0**. in that case none would be less or equal compared to the upper date you provide.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date
FROM  `test_table` 
WHERE date >=  '2010-04-01'
AND date <=  '2010-04-30';
```

Actually works in mysql. Remember that the standard structure of a `DATE type` field is `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: using postgre sql with date of type datetime